# I need to rearrange my data into a column and give the column a name

Tags: r, dataset, reshape

My data is displayed like this

Data = Predicted

```
      1      2              3             4
0.97949   1.29     3.02194675    0.41881809
```

> I would like to rearrange my data to look like this:

```
   DIH
1  0.97949
2  1.29
3  3.02194675
4  0.41881809
```

I would like to rearrange the data into a column and add a column name

Comment: What are you using to present the data like that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise what i was displaying, So i want to do this in R, I am using random Forrest to predict a variable in a data frame, Predicted is my result, i need to put my result into a column and give the column a heading

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming your original data is a data frame. If that's the case, you can just use `t()`  to convert it to a transposed dataframe:

```
# Create original data frame
original.df <- data.frame(t(c(0.97949, 1.29, 3.02194675, 0.41881809)))
colnames(original.df) <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
original.df

# 1    2        3         4
# 1 0.97949 1.29 3.021947 0.4188181


# Transpose it and rename the column
df <- data.frame(DIH=t(original.df))
df

# DIH
# 1 0.9794900
# 2 1.2900000
# 3 3.0219468
# 4 0.4188181
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

Data = cbind(DIH=Predicted)